# Quantum Fourier Transform : amplitude encoding of the time series?

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform, amplitude-encoding

I try to understand how to concretely use the Quantum Fourier Transform so as to retrieve the frequency amplitudes $g_{0},\dots, g_{N-1}$ out of the discrete time series $f_{0},\dots, f_{N-1}$ ($f_k\in\mathbb{R}$), just like it would be done in a classical way.

If I understand well, the first task is to build a quantum state which encodes the time series as its amplitude coefficients :
$$
\lvert \psi \rangle  = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}f_{k}\lvert k \rangle
$$

Then, the Quantum Circuit for the QFT performs the unitary :
$$
U\lvert \psi \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}g_{k}\lvert k \rangle
$$

**The question is that if I give you a time series, whatever, what is the procedure to build a corresponding $\lvert \psi \rangle$ ?**

**Also, how do you retrieve in the end of the circuit by measurements the $g_{k}$ ?**

Surprisingly, although there are many tutorials on the QFT, I found no pieces of information about these questions but this [post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32869/how-to-understand-quantum-fourier-transform-measurement-output), which seems to tackle the first question.

In the sequel, I try to address as far as I can the first question.

Obviously, for $\lvert \psi \rangle$ to be a valid state, the time series must be normalized :
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (f_k)^2 = 1
$$
which can be done easily by rescaling all $f_k$ coefficients.

For the sake of simplicity assume $N=4$, then :
$$
\lvert \psi \rangle = f_{0}\lvert 0 \rangle + f_{1}\lvert 1 \rangle +f_{2}\lvert 2 \rangle +f_{3}\lvert 3 \rangle =
f_{0}\lvert 00 \rangle + f_{1}\lvert 01 \rangle +f_{2}\lvert 10 \rangle +f_{3}\lvert 11 \rangle
$$

So we need two qubits, $q_0$ and $q_1$, the state of each qubit is :
$$
\lvert q_{0} \rangle =  \cos(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2})\lvert 0 \rangle + e^{i\varphi_{0}} \sin(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2})\lvert 1 \rangle,\quad
\lvert q_{1} \rangle =  \cos(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})\lvert 0 \rangle + e^{i\varphi_{1}} \sin(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})\lvert 1 \rangle
$$

The joint state of both qubit is then :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lvert q_{0}q_{1} \rangle = &\cos(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2}) \cos(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})\lvert 00 \rangle +
\cos(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2})\sin(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})\lvert 01 \rangle\\ &+
\sin(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})\lvert 10 \rangle+
\sin(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2})\sin(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})\lvert 11 \rangle
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where I assumed $\varphi_{0}= \varphi_{1} = 0$

Encoding the time series $f_{0},\dots, f_{N-1}$ into both qubits would consist in finding $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ such that :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f_{0} = \cos(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2}) \cos(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})&,\quad  f_{1} = \cos(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2})\sin(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2}),\quad \\
f_{2} = \sin(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})&,\quad  f_{3} = \sin(\frac{\theta_{0}}{2})\sin(\frac{\theta_{1}}{2})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
It would then be enough to rotate each qubit around $X$ axis with respective angle $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$, starting from $\lvert 0 \rangle$.

However, previous formula assume $\lvert \psi \rangle$ to be factorized (not entangled), which imposes a drastic condition on the time series :
$$
f_0f_3 = f_1 f_2
$$
it appears that this procedure is very limited. Is there a more general procedure ?

Comment: What you want to do is called "state preparation", and there are indeed known algorithms allowing to do it. You'll find some references in the answer to this question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18464/10454